# Mysql nested query access parent field value

Tags: mysql

I need to access the parent filed value in nested to nested query. Here is my query

```
    SELECT

        (
            sum(co.product_baseprice)  + (
select COALESCE(sum(testsum), 0) 
            from (SELECT
                        COALESCE (SUM(rm_baseprice), 0) * COALESCE (rm_quantity, 0) as testsum
                    FROM
                        rm_orders
                    WHERE
                        order_id = o.id
                    GROUP BY
                        id                      
                    order by 
                        id) as temp1)
        ) AS p_baseprice,
        (
            sum(co.product_vat) 
        ) AS p_vat,
        o.surcharge_value_id
    FROM
        orders AS o
    INNER JOIN customer_orders AS co ON o.id = co.order_id 
    WHERE
        1 = 1
        -- o.id = 62720
    GROUP BY
        o.id
    ORDER BY
        ValueAfterVAT DESC
    LIMIT 25;
```

In sub to sub query you find field `o.id` is the field of order table. When I try to execute this query I can see error like

```
"Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'o.id' in 'where clause'  0.000 sec"
```

How can I access o.id in nested to nested query.

Comment: why don't you simply join all three tables in the outer form? and btw, this will never work: sum(co.product_baseprice)  + (select COALESCE(sum(testsum), 0) , o.id ... " too many columns

Comment: My sub query is return multiple records, because I have used group by in sub query. I need total of all records, so I have added sum in outer query.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need to join with parent field in inner query, place it to outer one.

```
SELECT 
    sum(co.product_baseprice)  + (p_baseprice.testsum), 
     o.id, co.product_vat AS p_vat,
     o.surcharge_value_id
FROM
    orders AS o
    INNER JOIN customer_orders AS co ON o.id = co.order_id 
-- here query from SELECT was placed there. Note! LEFT OUTER
-- used since you used COALESCE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( 
         SELECT order_id,
                COALESCE (SUM(rm_baseprice), 0) * COALESCE (rm_quantity, 0) as testsum
         FROM
            rm_orders
         GROUP BY
            order_id
    ) as p_baseprice ON p_baseprice.order_id = o.id
    WHERE ...
```